# How many times can a student skip class in a 14 weeks semester?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

In a 14 weeks semester there are 5 school days each week. Johnny chooses each day if he goes to the University or skips the day. In how many ways can Johnny choose his attendance during the semester assuming he is not willing to skip the same day, two weeks in a row.

**What I've done so far:** I was thinking of a 5 digits long binary strings. $1$ stands for going to the University and $0$ stands for skip. Two adjacent strings can not have $0$ at the same index.

In this way, Johnny have $2^5$ options for the first week, and for further weeks he have $2^5$ $- \space$$(5-$'Sum of $1$'s in past week'$)$.

I don't know how to translate it into a formula or a function.

Comment: Is this what you want to use maths for?

Comment: @GitGud, Home exercise in discrete math, true story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question becomes quite a bit easier to think about when you realize that the five weekdays are independent. Thus, if there are $r$ ways to handle a given weekday, there are $r^5$ options in total.

For a given weekday, add a $15$th week, attach a non-skipped day after each skipped day, and consider in how many ways individual non-skipped days and pairs of skipped-plus-non-skipped days can be arranged. This is

$$
r=\sum_{k=0}^7\binom{15-k}k=987
$$

([Wolfram|Alpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20binom%20%282%20%2a%20n%20%2b%201%20-%20k,k%29%20for%20k=0..n%20where%20n%20=%207)), where $k$ is the number of skipped days.

If you want to avoid adding up the eight binomial coefficients, you can also derive the result using a recurrence relation. If for $m$ weeks there are $a_m$ options ending in a skipped day and $b_m$ options ending in a non-skipped day, then $a_{m+1}=b_m$ and $b_{m+1}=a_m+b_m$, so $b_{m+2}=b_{m+1}+b_m$ and thus also $c_{m+2}=c_{m+1}+c_m$ for $c_m=a_m+b_m$. This together with the initial conditions $c_0=1$ and $c_1=2$ shows that $c_m=F_{m+2}$, the $(m+2)$-th Fibonacci number, with $F_{16}=987$.

Comment: What do you mean by *five weekdays are independent*? The ability to skip a day in a given week is derived from the past week. And doesn't the fact that there are 14 weeks should make my relation work for $n = 14$?

Comment: I meant that the five weekdays are independent *of each other*. And I think you misunderstood my variable $n$; the number of days was meant to be $2n$; the $8$ was a typo; I've corrected it to $n=7$.

Comment: @Georgey: I've done away with $n$ altogether now; the new index $m$ is the number of weeks and is indeed $14$ in your case.

Comment: I understand your answer but I'm not sure why you haven't multiplied the final answer for a given day by 5 for each of the 5 weekdays.

Comment: @Georgey: I don't understand how an additional factor of $5$ might arise. Note that the first paragraph states that the result $r$ for one weekday needs to be taken to the fifth power.

Comment: ahh that's exactly what was missing. thanks.